# A Reverse Citation Index

Tags: reference-request

Given a published mathematics article, is there a way to find its tree of subsequent citations starting from the date of publication? Does such a (reverse bibliography) database exist?

*I'm at a student in a relatively well-known university with access to virtually every mathematics journal imaginable, but I can't seem to find such a simple and useful tool.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several, including the public [CiteSeerX](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/) and [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/) as well as many commercial databases.

Answer (score 6):

If you go to the AMS MathSciNet database, from each paper you can access to the list of papers citing it by clicking on the "From Reference" link from a "Citation" box in the upper right of the page.

See for istance the 255 papers citing Pierre Deligne's first paper on the Weil Conjectures here: 
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?refcit=340258&loc=refcit

Comment: It is probably woth mentioning that the link will only show the result to the people who have subscription ot MathSciNet.

Answer (score 2):

MathSciNet has a *From References* link that you can use to build the tree yourself, assuming your article is in MathSciNet.